# Change default theme of "project.net"

Tags: .net, asp.net, css, xhtml

I want to change complete theme of an open source project "project.net". Can anyone help me that how to change overall theme into custom theme.

NOTE: i already done with coloring and images change by CSS etc... my question is about change theme structure. e.g. and beautiful header in new theme. Accordion on left navigation etc.

Your quick prompt will be great!

Answer (score 1):

Use [master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) pages.